# how to give an array as option values in select using select2

Tags: jquery-select2

This is my html

```
<select class="compare-tag1">
 </select>
```

this is the array i want to be there as option values in the above select class:

```
optionVal = ["1","2","3"];
```

and this is how I am trying to do it with select2

```
$(".compare-tag1").select2({
    val: tagValuesArray
    });
```

Im getting no-error,but no values are shown in the dropdown. How can I get the values of the array as option values using select2?

Comment: Are you expecting these results to be displayed with the same text as the value? Or do you have another data source you are working with as well?

Comment: i have a dynamically populated array which is to be displayed using select-2. But it is something similar with less than 10 elements.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be looking for the `data` option, which will convert a an array of data objects (or single strings) into `<option>` tags.

```
$(".compare-tag1").select2({
  data: tagValuesArray
});
```